# Is there an operator like && that ignores return status?

Tags: command-line

I've discovered the following useful trick for long-running tasks on the command line:

```
do_some_task && make_a_noise
```

For instance, on OSX:

```
do_some_task && say 'done'
```

However, `&&` means "run the next command if the previous one returned 0 for success". If the first command fails, the second doesn't execute.

Is there a similar operator that means "do this regardless of the previous command's return status"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, the `;`:

```
do_some_task ; say 'done'
```

Comment: or if you want more baroque style: `do_some_task && say 'done' || say 'done'` :)